# ChakraUI not rendering with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

**UPDATE**: I'm running into the following error

*framer_motion__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.motion.custom is not a function*

My app isn't rendering on localhost. I can 'hello world' my create react app, but as soon as I edit in ChakraProvider, I'm unable to view my 'hello world'. I have tried traversing my ChakraProvider tag and that hasn't worked either.

index.js

```
..imports..

ReactDOM.render(
 
  
      <React.StrictMode>
        <ChakraProvider>
          <App/>
        </ChakraProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>
      
    
,

  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Are there

Comment: Try to remove `<React.StrictMode>` and test again.

Comment: I tried that as well and no solution. found this error on dev tools framer_motion__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.motion.custom is not a function

Comment: Have you installed Chakra with all its dependencies? It's not just the chakra package, it's `npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react@^11 @emotion/styled@^11 framer-motion@^6` [see docs](https://chakra-ui.com/guides/getting-started/cra-guide#1-installation). Otherwise, might want to show your package json or webpack config.

Answer (score 1):

Open the code in terminal.

Go into your project directory:

```
cd my-project
```

Install Chakra and emotion and framer dependencies:

```
npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react@^11 @emotion/styled@^11 framer-motion@^6
```

Then:

```
npm start
```

*Note: my-project refers to whatever project name given during npx-create-react-app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).